# Calling the set method of a constant object

Tags: c++, constants, stdvector

I'm doing an assignment where I'm given starter code and asked to fill it in. The starter code has three functions that ask me to add a `varargs` to an item and they are all similar but for different polymorphic objects.

```
 48 void Library::addKeywordsForItem(const Item* const item, int nKeywords, ...)
 49 {
 50     // the code in this function demonstrates how to handle a vararg in C++
 51
 52     va_list     keywords;
 53     string      keyword;
 54     bool        successFlag = false;
 55     sArray      keywordV;
 56
 57     va_start(keywords, nKeywords);
 58     for (int i = 0; i < nKeywords; i++) //This code adds the items to a map of set to create a fast access structure for keyword searches
 59     {
 60         keyword = va_arg(keywords, string);
 61         // do something with each keyword
 62         keywordV.push_back(keyword); //pushes keyword onto vector
 63         successFlag = addToSMap(item, keyword, keywordDbase); //This function is literally a copy/paste of the code
 64         //originally designed for this function
 65     }
 66     va_end(keywords);
 67
 68     const Item item2 = *item; //pointless attempt to circumvent const
 69
 70     item2.setKeywords(keywordV); //sends finished and unsorted vector into item object
 71
 72     if(!successFlag) //Should never execute
 73         cout << "This code reeks verily of wrongness.\n";
 74 }
```

My problem is that the function parameters specify a const object pointer so when I try to call `setKeywords` I get the following error.

```
Library.cpp: In member function ‘void Library::addKeywordsForItem(const Item*, int, ...)’:
Library.cpp:70:28: error: passing ‘const Item’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
  item2.setKeywords(keywordV); //sends finished and unsorted vector into item object
                            ^
In file included from Library.h:9:0,
                 from Library.cpp:4:
Item.h:30:7: note:   in call to ‘void Item::setKeywords(sArray&)’
  void setKeywords(sArray& keywords); //Takes unsorted vector
       ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

My problem is that the output of this program requires the object to store its keywords so I can print it. **I understand** that the entire point of const is to prevent me from altering the object.

How am I supposed to add the data needed for output if all the functions that take an `Item*` and the `varargs` (which are the only ones that could possibly deal with adding the vector) are `const`? Does anyone have any ideas?

P.S. `sArray` is `vector<string>` and this assignment is about polymorphism. I'm having a problem with dynamic_cast due to `const` but that's another question.

EDIT: We are not explicitly forbidden from changing the functions, but if I do then a lot of other code that was provided breaks.

It's worth noting that this code was designed to run on Visual Studio and is being edited on Vim. It's likely the teacher did little or no checking to make sure the assignment works on Linux.

Comment: Can you modify `addKeywordsForItem`? More specifically remove the first `const` from the declaration of `item`?

Comment: Are you sure you are asked to use vararg? You cannot use std :: string with it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the function is a part of the starter code. We aren't explicitly forbidden from changing it but I *would assume* that there is a way to complete the assignment as is. It's worth noting that this code was designed to run on **Visual Studio** and is being edited on **Vim**. It's likely the teacher did little or no checking to make sure the assignment works on Linux.

Comment: @Eugene everything from the definition of the function to "// do something with..." is starter code (plus the end of the loop and va_end(keywords)) so yes.

EDIT: I declared the bool and sArray though.

Comment: Does the assignment require `Item` to store the keywords or is that because of how you wrote your code? If the latter, you're probably expected to come up with a different solution.

Comment: @molbdnilo the output requires me to know the keywords of each item when passed to the << operator and the main code doesn't suggest that it is known there so the objects must store it.

Comment: I'm guessing this is impossible. Can someone verify there is no way to do what I want in the function?